# Change an array depend on check/uncheck checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to change `columns: [...]` depend on checkbox.

If I check the checkbox then it should give me `columns: ['model.name' ,'model.department']`

and when I uncheck it should change it to `columns: ['model.name']` - removed `model.department`

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
    columns: ['model.name', 'model.department'],
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.*" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>



<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model=options.columns>Department</label>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a function to the scope in the controller to add or remove the item depending on if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
$scope.addRemoveItem = function (checked, value) {
  if (checked) {
    $scope.options.columns.push(value);
  }
  else {
    var index = $scope.options.columns.indexOf(value);
    $scope.options.columns.splice(index);
  }
};
```

Then use ng-change to call this function when the checkbox is changed:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="departmentChecked" ng-change="addRemoveItem(departmentChecked, 'model.department')">Department</label>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zv94fCB8GG49tH3ZnIPA?p=preview)